# org-mode in windows

Tags: windows-xp, emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to get the org-mode that came with my emacs-22.3 to work, with no luck. What I added to my .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Program Files/Emacs/emacs-22.3/lisp/textmodes")
(require 'org-install)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org$" . org-mode))
(define-key global-map "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(define-key global-map "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(setq org-log-done t)
```

And I'm sure that there's an org.elc in the textmodes directory. I start emacs with a script called RunEmacs.bat that contains the following

```
set HOME=.
emacs-22.3\bin\runemacs.exe
```

The error I get is

> An error has occurred while loading `c:/Program Files/Emacs/.emacs':
>
> File error: Cannot open load file, org-install

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the org-mode package that came with the Emacs 22, then no need to install it.  Just run the command `M-x org-mode` on any file that you intend to use as an org file.

In addition, the line `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org$" . org-mode))` that you added to your .emacs file will automatically start org-mode for any file that ends with the extension *.org.

Remove the line `(require 'org-install)` from your .emacs file since that is only applicable if you had downloaded a separate org-mode package if, for example, you were using an older version of Emacs that does not have org-mode.

Comment: OK, thanks! I could have sworn that when I looked at http://orgmode.org/manual/Activation.html#Activation it had the 'require' line in there, and then the 'add-to-list' was something I found by searching the internet.